# crystal reports how to overrule the parameter field value in a subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I use a parameter field value in a main report and 3 subreports, this is a value like 20121016, in one of the subreports i want to overrule this value 20121016 and or +1 and or -1 so that the result of the record selection for this subreport is more variable.
Can anybody help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a maximum and minimum parameter in the sub report then add two new formulas, one deducting a day and one adding a day to the date:

```
Dateadd("DAY",1, {?MyDate})
Dateadd("DAY",-1, {?MyDate})
```

And pass these to the sub report.

In the sub report record selection do something like:

```
{MyTable.MyDateField} >= {?MinDate} and
{MyTable.MyDateField} <= {?MaxDate}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, how can i resolve this if this above mentioned value is a string-value?

Comment: If they are strings you can convert both values to numbers: `ToNumber({MyTable.MyDateField}) >= ToNumber({?MinDate}`)

Comment: hey,  how to do subreport parameter values passing if i need a parameter that the main report didn't use?thank you